# How pytz calculates time for different timezones

Tags: python-3.x, pytz

This may sound stupid but I just want to confirm how pytz calculates time for different timezones?

Does it rely on the local machine's time and calculates relatively, or,  it has a mechanism to directly access network time for confirmation. I didn't find any info on the [pytz documentation page](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pytz` has no concept of “current time”. It works with the `datetime` objects that are passed to it. And `datetime.datetime.now()` or `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` access the system clock of the local machine.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, it relies on the local machine time. It works without network connection after all.